# Linked list - append, insert, print

Tags: c, linked-list, pointers

I am a beginner in C and am learning linked lists.  I have made a program to implement a linked list, allowing certain operations on the linked list.

There are 3 functions:

- `addnode()` adds node to end of list
- `printlist()` prints the whole linked list
- `insertnode()` inserts a node after a specified node

### addnode():

```
void addnode(struct node **head)
{
     if (*head == NULL)
     {
        struct node *newNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        *head = newNode;
        printf("enter data: ");

        scanf("%d",&((*head)->data));
        (*head)->node = NULL;
     }
     else
     {
        struct node *newNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("enter data: ");
        scanf("%d", &(newNode->data));
        newNode->node = NULL;

        struct node *temp = *head;
        while (temp->node != NULL)
        {
              temp = temp->node;
        }

        temp->node = newNode;
     }
}
```

### printlist():

```
void printlist(struct node **head)
{
     struct node *temp = *head;
     while (temp->node != NULL)
     {
           printf("%d--", temp->data);
           temp = temp->node;
     }
     printf("NULL\n");
}
```

### insertnode():

```
int insertnode(struct node **head)
{
    int i, j = 0;

    printf("enter what node you want to insert node after: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    struct node *temp = *head;

    while (temp->node != NULL)
    {
          if (i-1 == j)
          {
             struct node *newNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

             printf("enter data: ");
             scanf("%d", &i);

             newNode->data = i;
             newNode->node = temp->node;

             temp->node = newNode;
             break;
          }
          temp = temp->node; j++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How well have I implemented these functions?

Is my code easy to read?

What could I improve?

Does it abide by popular good coding practices?

Here is my `main()` function and function prototypes:

```
struct node
{
       int data;
       struct node *node;
};

void addnode(struct node **head);
void printlist(struct node **head);
int insertnode(struct node **head);

int main()
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    addnode(&head);
    addnode(&head);
    addnode(&head);
    addnode(&head);

    printlist(&head);

    insertnode(&head);
    printlist(&head);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're missing includes of the library headers which provide function prototypes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

---

A popular naming convention is to use a distinctive prefix (rather than a suffix) for the function names, so that they appear together in alphabetical lists: `node_add()`, `node_insert()`, `node_print()`.

---

We're missing a function to return the memory we're using.  If we run under Valgrind, we see that we leak the memory we allocated, so we really need a `node_free()` function.

---

`addnode()` performs two functions: reading user input and inserting the node.  It would be more useful if we separate the functions:

```
addnode(struct node **head, int value);
```

The same is true for `insertnode()`.

---

`insertnode()` always returns 0.  It looks like you were anticipating a different return value when the target node wasn't found, but didn't implement that.

---

`printnode()` would be better if it weren't restricted to writing only to standard output.  Users might want to write to standard error, or a file, a device or a socket.

---

We are not robust when allocating memory:

> ```
>          struct node *newNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
>          newNode->data = i;
>          newNode->node = temp->node;
> ```

`malloc()` returns a `void*`, which can be assigned directly to any object-pointer type without needing a cast.  A good practice for computing the required size is to measure the size of the pointed-to value, rather than its type:

```
         struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);
```

Then we need a test before we dereference the pointer:

```
         if (!newNode) {
             return NODE_FAILURE;
         }
```

---

The other area where we need to be more robust is user input.  We're ignoring the return value from `scanf()`, but that means we have no idea whether it succeeded or not.  That leads to unpredictable behaviour, as Valgrind reveals:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./265776 <<<''
==2932516== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2932516== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2932516== Using Valgrind-3.16.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2932516== Command: ./265776
==2932516== 
==2932516== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2932516==    at 0x48DE29F: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)
==2932516==    by 0x48C9D9A: printf (printf.c:33)
==2932516==    by 0x1092E7: printlist (265776.c:66)
==2932516==    by 0x1091B0: main (265776.c:19)
==2932516== 
==2932516== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==2932516==    at 0x48C3EFB: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==2932516==    by 0x48DD8B7: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)
==2932516==    by 0x48C9D9A: printf (printf.c:33)
==2932516==    by 0x1092E7: printlist (265776.c:66)
==2932516==    by 0x1091B0: main (265776.c:19)
==2932516== 
==2932516== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2932516==    at 0x48C3F0C: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==2932516==    by 0x48DD8B7: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)
==2932516==    by 0x48C9D9A: printf (printf.c:33)
==2932516==    by 0x1092E7: printlist (265776.c:66)
==2932516==    by 0x1091B0: main (265776.c:19)
==2932516== 
==2932516== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2932516==    at 0x48DE660: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)
==2932516==    by 0x48C9D9A: printf (printf.c:33)
==2932516==    by 0x1092E7: printlist (265776.c:66)
==2932516==    by 0x1091B0: main (265776.c:19)
==2932516== 
==2932516== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2932516==    at 0x48DDA2E: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)
==2932516==    by 0x48C9D9A: printf (printf.c:33)
==2932516==    by 0x1092E7: printlist (265776.c:66)
==2932516==    by 0x1091B0: main (265776.c:19)
==2932516== 
enter data: enter data: enter data: enter data: 0--0--0--NULL
==2932516== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2932516==    at 0x109362: insertnode (265776.c:83)
==2932516==    by 0x1091BC: main (265776.c:21)
==2932516== 
==2932516== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2932516==    at 0x48DE29F: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)
==2932516==    by 0x48C9D9A: printf (printf.c:33)
==2932516==    by 0x1092E7: printlist (265776.c:66)
==2932516==    by 0x1091C8: main (265776.c:22)
==2932516== 
==2932516== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2932516==    at 0x48DE660: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)
==2932516==    by 0x48C9D9A: printf (printf.c:33)
==2932516==    by 0x1092E7: printlist (265776.c:66)
==2932516==    by 0x1091C8: main (265776.c:22)
==2932516== 
==2932516== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2932516==    at 0x48DDA2E: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)
==2932516==    by 0x48C9D9A: printf (printf.c:33)
==2932516==    by 0x1092E7: printlist (265776.c:66)
==2932516==    by 0x1091C8: main (265776.c:22)
==2932516== 
enter what node you want to insert node after: 0--0--0--NULL
==2932516== 
==2932516== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2932516==     in use at exit: 64 bytes in 4 blocks
==2932516==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 2 frees, 5,184 bytes allocated
==2932516== 
==2932516== 64 (16 direct, 48 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 4
==2932516==    at 0x483877F: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2932516==    by 0x1091F1: addnode (265776.c:37)
==2932516==    by 0x109180: main (265776.c:14)
==2932516== 
==2932516== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2932516==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==2932516==    indirectly lost: 48 bytes in 3 blocks
==2932516==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2932516==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2932516==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

---

With some care, we don't need a separate code path for an empty list:

```
int node_add(struct node **head, int value)
{
    while (*head) {
        head = &(*head)->node;
    }

    struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);
    if (!newNode) {
        return 1;
    }

    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->node = NULL;
    *head = newNode;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this insightful look into my programs pros and cons i appreciate it a lot ! =)